# Hide Legend and Scale information on surface plot using pandas, plotly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-visualization, plotly, data-analysis

I am at my wits end but so far did not find any documentation to solve my specific issue. I am using `jupyter notebook`.

I have two data frames, `df1` & `df2`.

```
# libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# df1 & df2
np.random.seed(0)
dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=6)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))
```

I have two surface plots:

```
layout = go.Layout(
    title='Random Numbers',
    autosize=False,
    width=500,
    height=500,
    margin=dict(
        l=65,
        r=50,
        b=65,
        t=90
    )
)

df1.iplot(kind="surface", layout=layout)
df2.iplot(kind="surface", layout=layout)
```

I have three problems:

1. I need to plot them side by side as in *(row = 1 & column = 2)*.
2. The scale legend is either removed or is shared.
3. The `x` and `y` in the axes are removed. I do not need to change them, just get rid of these.

[image: Sample Surface from df1]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: To remove the scale legend in pure `plotly` (i.e. without `cufflinks`), you would do `data1 = [go.Surface(z=df1.as_matrix(), showscale=False)]` (the import part is `showscale=False`). I'm not sure how `cufflinks` works but maybe that information helps you a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry if this doesn't answer your question directly but I would suggest using `plotly` without `cufflings`.

```
import plotly

# Define scene which changes the default attributes of the chart
scene = dict(
    xaxis=dict(title=''),
    yaxis=dict(title=''),
    zaxis=dict(title='')
)

# Create 2 empty subplots
fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2,
                                 specs=[[{'is_3d': True}, {'is_3d': True}]])
# Add df1
fig.append_trace(dict(type='surface', x=df1.index, y=df1.columns, z=df1.as_matrix(), 
                      colorscale='Viridis', scene='scene1', showscale=False), 1, 1)

# Add df2
fig.append_trace(dict(type='surface', x=df2.index, y=df2.columns, z=df2.as_matrix(), 
                      colorscale='RdBu', scene='scene2', showscale=False), 1, 2)

# Set layout and change defaults with scene
fig['layout'].update(title='Random Numbers', height=400, width=800)
fig['layout']['scene1'].update(scene)
fig['layout']['scene2'].update(scene)

# Use plotly offline to display the graph
plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT:**

To answer your third question, you can use `.update(scene)` to change the axis attributes. Details are in the code above.

Comment: My initial reason for using `cufflinks` was to go offline. For some reason, when I tried using pure `plotly`, it could not get the graphs, just blank canvas. Will try again tomorrow when I am on the network. I have a feeling, this just might work.

Comment: If you use plotly offline, you have to use `plotly.offline.plot()` instead of `plotly.plotly.iplot()`. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: If I use `plotly.offline.plot()`, it opens up a html page with the plots and does not display it in the notebook. I remember now, it was this issue that forced me to use `cufflinks` for offline plotting. If i replace offline with `plotly.plotly.iplot()` and keep my original import for `cf`, it works. I will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used this and working:

```
show_colorbar=False
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35803268)